# Technical solution for large geospatial data

Tags: python, html, leaflet, geospatial, folium

I made an app which places points on the map within certain polygons.It is Windows Forms app with simple UI.These points are also pre-filtered.I use Python,geopandas and folium libraries exactly.As a result, the program saves .html map with all layers and .xlsx sammari.However,datasets can be really huge and on this html map there can be,for example,100000 points.Obviously,neither Google Earth nor Browser can deal with these big .html maps.So,are there any solution to work with this big amount of data?

Maybe there are folium enthusiasts?Can marker clusters improve situation?

Comment: "_Can marker clusters improve situation?_" yes it can. Then it may not exactly fit your requirements, but we do not know what those are.

Answer (score 0):

100,000 points is not really large amount of data these days. Even pure web-based tools can draw that. In the JavaScript / Web world I know [deck.gl](https://deck.gl) which scales well beyond this size before you need marker clusters (but they might be a better way to represent such data even if you can technically put 100k markers on the map).

I don't have personal experience programming with deck.gl, but the tool I frequently use (Google BigQuery GeoViz - https://bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/) can draw 100k points, and more. It is a client-side page, it gets data from BigQuery, but it should be easy to adopt it to draw static resource (it is an open source tool), or find another solution to use in deck.gl examples.